# MATERIALIZED VIEW REFRESH FAST AGGREGATION + OPERATION => ORA-12015

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

I have a table with an identifier column (code) and a value column(val).

I have a functional materialized view on oracle 11g :

```
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "MYVIEW"
     BUILD IMMEDIATE
     REFRESH fast ON demand
     WITH ROWID 
     AS      
      SELECT 
      code,   
      sum(val)
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY code
;
```

But if i edit like this (just add "+10" to the sum column) :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "MYVIEW"
     BUILD IMMEDIATE
     REFRESH fast ON demand
     WITH ROWID 
     AS      
      SELECT 
      code,   
      sum(val) +10
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY code
;
```

I have an error :

ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query

Why ??

Comment: Have you [analysed the view query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#DWHSG8218) to see why it isn't fast-refreshable?

Comment: Not Capable of:

  REFRESH_FAST

  REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT
    aggregate function nested within an expression...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found : do it with 2 materialized views...
One for the aggregation
One for the operation +10